# SpectrumJS, dragger and slider position issue with display: none container

Tags: javascript, css, color-picker, spectrum

I need to use SpectrumJS inside a div that has the attribute "display: none", but when I remove the attribute to make the div visible, the position of the dragger and the slider does not correspond to the color set. If in container div the attribute "display"  isn't set, everything works correctly.

HELP!

Comment: It will be easier to debug your problem if you provide some code snippets.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jz37hLre/2/

Answer (score 0):

depending on your usage of the plugin, you could maybe re-initialize #flat2 after showing it.

```
<div>
    <input type='text' id="flat" />
</div>
<div style="display: none" id="container">
    <input type='text' id="flat2" />
</div>
<input type="button" value="show div" onclick="$('#container').css('display', 'inline');$('#flat2').spectrum({
    flat: true,
    showInput: true,
    color: '#00aeef'
});"/>
```

---

Added: 
or try to initialize and then hide:
http://jsfiddle.net/neildaemond/jz37hLre/4/

Comment: Unfortunately, the reality is not so simple, the example I posted only served to understand the problem. In my code using spectrum through a directive of angular within a plugin for managing dropdown and there is no way to reinitialize the instance of spectrum.

Comment: However I think this is an anomalous behavior due to a bug of spectrum.

Comment: Yeah, can't really make out how you're using it with angular, but i did notice that if you initialize and then add 'display:none', it will work: http://jsfiddle.net/neildaemond/jz37hLre/3/